# Keyboard/mouse don't work after Ubuntu 16.10 upgrade on MacPro 11,1

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, mouse, 16.10

After upgrading MacbookPro 11.1 13" from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10, both keyboard and mouse stopped working. External USB mouse/keyboard also do not work. I can only do a hard shutdown (powerd btn hold). The computer seems to be functioning otherwise - it connected to wifi, goes into sleep on lid close and wakes up.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue after upgrading a Lenovo Yoga 2 form 16.04 to 16.10. Ever find a fix?

Comment: Yep, returned the mac, and bought a Dell XPS 13.  Works great :)

Comment: ha!  In case its useful to anyone else, I managed to upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04 using the software keyboard to authenticate. Everything works fine in 17.04.

Comment: Just confirming. Upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04 using software keyboard fixed it for me. Thanks for the tip. Maybe worth mentioning as an answer?